# Impute missing value: transpose or not?

Tags: scikit-learn, missing-data, data-imputation

I'm building a model that fills the missing values from a Dataframe that contains the number of visitors for different stores, each day:

| day | store_a | store_b | store_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2021-01-02 | 110 | 220 | 290 |
| 2021-01-03 | 50 | 110 | 170 |
| 2021-01-04 | **NAN** | 220 | 290 |
| 2021-01-05 | 7 | 16 | **NAN** |
| 2021-01-06 | 90 | **NAN** | **NAN** |

I'm using the [IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer) class from scikit-learn, this method of imputation puts aside one column at each step and train an estimator on the other columns to predict the column that was put aside.

My question is: should I transpose my dataframe or not?

If I keep my dataframe (1 line = 1 day, 1 column = 1 store), this means that we can completely predict the number of visitors in a store in a particular day just by looking at the other stores.

But if I transpose my dataframe (1 line = 1 store, 1 line = 1 day), this means that we can predict the number of visitors just by looking at the history of one store.

I guess one simple way to check if I should transpose is comparing the RMSE of the two methods but I wanted some explanation instead of "method A works better, move along."

Comment: How many rows/columns do you have?

Comment: In my training dataset I had 93 days and 300 stores, so my dataframe has 93 lines and 300 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just by eyeballing the data i would think the number of visitors for store A on jan 4th is around 110. Basically it is always approximately half of Store B on any given day.

It seems like the number of visitors across stores are correlated, so you could potentially use simple linear regression to get a reasonable estimate for any given day.

Comment: thanks for the insight but this was just a minimal example :) 
The real data is much more complex, with more than a thousand stores for multiple years

Comment: Even if you had thousands of stores, you could still find pairs that are highly correlated and use them to impute the other.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I am trying to do